# Python FastApi error 422 (Unprocessable Entity)

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, backend, fastapi

When I use a POST request to send form data from a JS script running on port 5500 using XMLHttpRequest to my backend which is a FastAPI app running on port 8000, I am always met with this error `Unprocessable Entity`.
Here is the server-side:

```
origins = ["https://localhost:5500"]
app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=origins,
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)


@app.post("/test")
def test(username: str = Form(...)):
    print(f"########### Received {username} #############")
```

And here is the client-side code:

```
async function sendData() {
    formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('username', 'Kareem');
    const response = await fetch('http://localhost:8000/test', {
        method: 'POST',
        data: formData
    })
}
```

Comment: What is the error in the response body?

Comment: should the origin a https or http as it is a localhost?

Comment: @MahirMahbub I've tried both

Comment: I tried your code in my server. It is working fine. I think their ia configuration error in backend or problem in frontend. Did you tested the api in swgger or other tools?

Comment: @Mause Response {type: "cors", url: "http://localhost:8000/test", redirected: false, status: 422, ok: false, …}
body: (...)
bodyUsed: false
headers: Headers {}
ok: false
redirected: false
status: 422
statusText: "Unprocessable Entity"
type: "cors"
url: "http://localhost:8000/test"
__proto__: Response

Comment: @MahirMahbub I tested in swagger and everything works fine. The problem is when I send the data from a js script. Did you see the response object I just posted? Can you tell me repoducible steps that you did that i can try?

Comment: Eliminate Async and await, try and let me know. Also check the api url.

Comment: Actually I am not well aware of frontend machanism.

Comment: @MahirMahbub I eliminated them, still the same problem, however now the response object isn't logged.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I had a same problem . I used URLSearchParams.

This is my code

```js
let urlencoded = new URLSearchParams();
urlencoded.append("username", username);
urlencoded.append("password", password);


try {
    setLoading(true);
    const response =  await fetch("http://127.0.0.1:5000/login", {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
             "Content-Type" : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        },
        body: urlencoded,
        redirect: 'follow'

    })
```

Comment: Could you explain a little bit why? The code snippet is throwing an error so it's hard to understand in context.